# JavaScript: Copy text without format, but keep the links

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, format, copy

I am using the following JS code to copy text without formatting. Is it possible to copy without formatting, but keep the links?

```js
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}
```

```css
Some text with a link.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bodytext" style="text-align:justify">

<p><b><span style="font-size: 24pt">Some text with a </span><b>
<span style="font-size: 24pt"><a href="https://example.com/">link</a>.</span></p>

</div>


<br>
<button id="mybtn" onclick="copyToClipboard('#bodytext')">Copy</button>
```

Comment: Not sure the issue - you're copying whatever you put in $temp so put the text + href in: `$temp.val($(element).text() + " : " + element.href).select();` - but looking closer, you're calling it on a div and that div doesn't have "links" - so unclear what your expected output would be - perhaps `$(element).text() + ":" + $(element).find("a").map((i,e)=>e.href).join(":")` ?  or `$(element).text() + ":" + $(element).find("a").map((i,e)=>$(e).html()).join(":")`

Comment: It's not possible to copy a link from an input element, as the element contains plain text only. If you want to copy a link, you've to clone the content to copy into an element which can have HTML (ex. `div`), remove the style attribute, create a selection of the element(s) and then copy. The paste result depends on the app and the target element you're pasting the content to, as the clipboard stores the data in multiple formats.